# Django form: *Nothing* happens when submit button is clicked

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm probably missing something very basic but I'm stumped.

My HTML form (in a Django template):

```
<form id="site_signout" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     <input type="submit" value="sign in">
</form>
```

In my browser (running my site on the dev server), when I click on the `<input>` button, nothing happens.  Like, nothing nothing.  Normally something would show in Terminal such as

```
[22/Apr/2014 08:29:17] "POST /my/url/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Or in Firebug, I would see something about a `POST` in the HTML tab of the Net panel.  But I see nothing.  Literally nothing happens when I click the button.

Other submit buttons (for other forms) on my site work just fine.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT:** The relevant part of my view is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    pdb.set_trace()
```

That's all I have for the form right now because I want to examine what is posted in this scenario before I write more code.

**EDIT:** My intention is to simply POST to the same page (URL) that the form is on.  As I understand it, this should be achievable by simply omitting the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element altogether.  This is how I started but since it didn't work, I tried a couple of other options such as `action="/"`, which is what I originally posted above.  However, my intention is to have the form POST handled by the same view as the form itself.  Therefore I've edited my original code sample to omit the `action` attribute altogether to clarify this point.

Here is my top-level urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^inspection/', include('main_inspection.urls') ),
    ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is main_inspection.urls with the relevant URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('main_inspection.views',
    url(r'^home/$', 'home', name="inspection_home"),
    ...
)
```

The URL for the view in question (on my dev server) is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/inspection/home/
```

Comment: Can you show us the view for url "/"?

Comment: show us your urls.py content that assign to "/" address, without that we couldn't help you.

Comment: @MortezaIpo, actually I don't have anything assigned to "/", but I have tried also "" and "." as well as no `action` attribute at all; none of these makes a difference.

Comment: Until we have more information, Im just going to throw this out there.  After I've been running the dev server for too long and making too many changes (I havent been able to identify steps to recreate the problem unfortunately), the server seems to break.  It will look like it's working, but certain things just dont register: changes in admin, widgets being loaded, changes to models, etc.  If you still cant identify the problem, try restarting the server, then the terminal, and finally your computer.

Comment: @GChorn could you add your urls.py content in your post? when should read that.

Comment: @GChorn are you sure that 'home' will work? what about views.home? add return HttpResponse instead of pdb.... to check your form will posted or not

Comment: @MortezaIpo, sorry for wasting your time, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be quite silly, and not discoverable by anyone reading the above question:

I had some JS capturing any click event happening inside the div in which the form was located.

Lesson learned: when something really strange seems to be happening at the basic HTML level, check to make sure you didn't write any stupid JS code that is producing the effect.

Comment: yes , I agree with you . when we get problems in projects , we should check all of things that may depend in our problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL about "/" should be something like this:

```
...
url(r'^$','yourapp.views.index',name="base_address"),
...
```

It will run **"yourapp.views.index"** when you call **"/"** address.

If you want to set an address in you form action attribute try to set name of address instead:

```
<form id="site_signout" method="POST" action="{% url 'base_address' %}">{% csrf_token %}
     <input type="submit" value="sign in">
</form>
```

We defined **"base_address"** name in urls that assigned to **"/"** address and then used that with **"url"** method in template.